# How to check for object value = empty array?

Tags: php, arrays, object, iteration, is-empty

Iterating through an object... API response... for some strange reason, certain empty values are coming up as an empty array... i.e.

```
$foo->bar = array()
```

or

```
$foo->bar = array(0)
```

But when I try to check with:

```
if ( empty($foo->bar) )
```

Or even:

```
if ( is_array($foo->bar) )
```

It's not catching it. I've been converting the whole object to an array to get around this, which works, but is costing performance.

Is there something I'm missing here?

EDIT:

Going back, it looks like I mixed up my array with my object. What I NEED to check for is an empty value in a response such as:

```
[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [RecordID] => 14
        [SomethingID] => 1
        [SomethingName] => OKAY
        [Integer] => 0
        [String] => String
        [AnotherInteger] => 1
        [Empty] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [SomethingElseID] => 0
    )
```

How do I check if $object->Empty is EMPTY?

EDIT:

var_dump shows:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1343 (8) { 

    ["RecordID"]=> string(2) "14" 
    ["SomethingID"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["SomethingName"]=> string(4) "OKAY" 
    ["Integer"]=> string(1) "0" 
    ["String"]=> string(6) "String" 
    ["AnotherInteger"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["Empty"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#1355 (0) { } 
    ["SomethingElseID"]=> string(1) "0" 

}
```

Comment: `array(0)` isn't an empty array, and [`empty($arr)`](http://us1.php.net/empty) *does* work.

Comment: Wait, what are the expected and actual outputs for each of the arrays (`array()` and `array(0)`)?

Comment: array(0) has only come up once or twice, randomly... yet empty($array) is NOT producing the desired result. empty($array), having output the object and seen that the value of the array is indeed empty, does not produce a TRUE response when checking with empty().

Comment: is it possible that the response produced from the API (on a Windows machine - ours being Linux) is somehow returning array() as a string, i.e. "array()" rather than an actual array? Is this even remotely possible?

Comment: Can you please copy and paste your output from the API

Comment: `$test = array(0);
echo empty($test) ? 'Empty' : 'Full';`

Will return `Full`

Comment: @JD Vangsness - see edit, above

Comment: Check out http://us3.php.net/SimpleXMLElement

Comment: The solution was simple enough: [PHP: is_object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php). Durk kur durrr....

Answer (score 2):

Use `empty($array)` ([docs](http://php.net/empty)) to determine if you array is empty.

**EDIT**

Yes, I noticed OP stated he uses `empty()` but you can always do something like:

```
function isArrayEmpty($arr) {
   return (count($arr) == 0);
}
```

for verification purposes. `empty()` is (theoretically) the way to go. And you can always use `var_dump()` or `print_r()` to inspect why `empty()` claims array is not empty while you bet it should be.

Also @chameleon answer lead me to this: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=24915 - if your class is using `__get()` then using `count()` instead of `empty()` may be the workaround.

Comment: OP states they are using `empty()`

Comment: Then either array is not empty or OP found a bug in PHP.

Comment: seriously doubt it's a bug. digging deeper. driving me nuts right now... maybe need to rest the eyes a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `foreach` to determine if an array is empty, although I recommend @Marcin's method

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
  if(empty($value)){
    unset($array[$key]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your object uses the magical `__get()` function to access an object's properties, an `empty()` check will fail unless you are using PHP 5.5+.

From the docs:

```
Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in 
a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: empty(trim($name)).
```

If you use the magical method to access the property, it is like doing empty($object->__get($property))

EDIT: Note that though the docs mention that it results in a parse error, I've never actually seen it result in a PHP error, I believe it simply returns false